# python pandas read_excel not catching exceptions

Tags: python, pandas, try-catch, keyerror, except

> EDIT: I have found that the reason my exceptions aren't catching is
>   because they are actually being thrown by a different function to
>   where I have put the try except block. Rookie mistake. If a mod would like to delete
>   or suggest how I may edit the question please do. I haven't deleted it due to it
>   having an answer.

I am trying to add some error handling to my code which reads data from an excel spreadsheet using the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library.
I have not done this type of exception handling in Python before so not sure what I am doing wrong.

In my following snippet of code the `FileNotFoundError` exception works just fine when I put the xlsx file where my program can't find it. My program exits cleanly displaying the message and has the correct exit status.

```
try:
    xdf = pd.read_excel(xlsxdir + 'web_targets.xlsx', 'targets', skiprows=[0], index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A:F")
except KeyError as e:
    print("Expected column headers not found")
    sys.exit(1)
except TypeError as e:
    print("Type Error")
    sys.exit(1)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print("Excel file not found " + str(e))
    sys.exit(1)
```

Unfortunately when the program can find the file, but has an unexpected column key/heading neither the `KeyError` or `ValueError` exceptions catch and I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/justin/projects/web_targets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4410, in get_value
    return libindex.get_value_at(s, key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 44, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 45, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas/_libs/util.pxd", line 98, in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at
  File "pandas/_libs/util.pxd", line 83, in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./create_new_configs.py", line 60, in <module>
    for record in xdfToDict(xdf):
  File "./create_new_configs.py", line 29, in xdfToDict
    'app': row['App'],
  File "/home/justin/projects/web_targets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/home/justin/projects/web_targets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4418, in get_value
    raise e1
  File "/home/justin/projects/web_targets/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4404, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'App'
```

I initially didn't have the `TypeError` exception but I thought maybe since it is the first exception you must have to "catch" it first so I added it but nothing changed.

I have done some searching around and as far as I can tell I am doing the same as examples for e.g. `KeyValue` exceptions.

I would just like to be able to catch some potential data entry errors and return to the BASH script I will use to call this program with a suitable exit code.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    xdf = pd.read_excel(xlsxdir + 'web_targets.xlsx', 'targets', skiprows=[0], index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A:F")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

You can directly catch via Exception class. Although this is not recommended, this can ensure that your program exits gracefully and returns to the bash script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed everything and just used one `Exception` block. Again it works perfectly for `FileNotFoundError` but I still get get the trace-back in the other case.

Comment: This should not happen. I think this stack trace is just because of print(e) and the program is exiting gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rohit Patil. Please see my edit at the top of the original question. The reason it is not working is because the exception was coming from a different part of the code to where I had my try/catch.